# CSS display:block issue

Tags: css

we have the following code:
http://jsfiddle.net/DVwmJ/

As you can see, the green line is 4px after the red line (we do not expect this).
Anyone know why if I uncomment the "display:block" css declaration for the span element the lines overlap (as expected)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which browser are you referring to? I see no green line (Google Chrome)

Comment: @Curt: You need to hover over the text

Comment: @Amberlamps Cheers I see it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `display: block`, the `span` remains an inline element. The extra 4 pixels of height comes from the space left for [descenders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) in letters. An observation: if you change the `font-size`, [the amount of extra height also changes](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/DVwmJ/14/).

If you didn't want to specify `display: block`, [you could set `vertical-align: top`](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/DVwmJ/13/), which is different to the default of `vertical-align: baseline`.